# How we can do the distributed test execution with selenium grid in protractor

Tags: protractor, selenium-grid

How we can do the distributed test execution with selenium grid in protractor,so that each instance of browser should execute different tests.Also how we can pass parameters to different nodes(consider one browser instance is running in each of the nodes),so that by identifying this parameters in each node it should execute different tests.How we can do this?Thanks in advance